# PostsControllerTest Error with Simple Ruby on Rails Program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Full Code on GitHub, https://github.com/Marium36/blog

I am taking online Ruby on Rails course that guides us to create simple blog application.

Running this on Ubuntu 18.04

Following commands work

```
> rails new blog
> cd blog
> rails generate scaffold Post title:string body:text
> rails generate scaffold Comment post:references body:text
> rake db:migrate
> rake routes
> rails server
```

As soon as I run this (per the course)

```
> rake db:test:load
> rake test
```

I get error

```
Run options: --seed 62159

# Running:

.E

Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_post:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:57:in `destroy'
    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'


rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:41

............

Finished in 7.151961s, 1.9575 runs/s, 2.2371 assertions/s.
14 runs, 16 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Do you have the relationships set up properly in your models?  I am speaking specifically about `dependent: :destroy` as it relates to trying to delete a post that a comment belongs to, which it looks like you may be trying to do here.

Comment: @RockwellRice I have no idea how to do this (as I am following beginner video). Can you post a link to tutorial. Will try to follow this.

Comment: @Marium We can't answer your question as it stands because the error is coming from your tests and you haven't shared those.

Comment: Can you just post your code from the post and comment model? That would make providing an answer easier I suspect

Comment: coming right up .....

Comment: @RockwellRice See repository, https://github.com/Marium36/blog

Comment: @coreyward See repository, https://github.com/Marium36/blog

Comment: Man, if u are justing studying, remove this post test controller and parents

Comment: You have a pretty solid answer below.  I would read through that and notice the change to the post model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're experiencing (Foreign Key constraint failed) is telling you that you have a foreign key constraint in your database that is not met when some particular piece of code is run.

**What is a foreign key?***
In relational databases—like MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQLite—you typically have tables of data that *relate* to one another in some way. It's very common for rows in those tables to reference one another using an ID, which is referred to as the “key”. You might have, as you do here, a `comments` table with a `post_id` column that references the `id` column of the `posts` table. In this case, the `post_id` is referencing the *foreign* key `posts.id`.

**What is a constraint?**
In relational databases, constraints provide a way to ensure the integrity of your data. A constraint can do things like ensure a `price` column is never negative (i.e. verify based on the data itself), ensure one value is lower than another in the same row, or verify that the data matches another record in another table entirely.

**Putting it together: what is a foreign key constraint?** 
A foreign key constraint, if you haven't already put it together, is just a special type of constraint that ensures that the “foreign record”—the row in the table you're referencing—actually exists. In this case, `comments.post_id` has a foreign key constraint on `posts.id`, which ensures that a row can't be added to the `comments` table with a `post_id` that doesn't exist in the `posts.id` column.

**So why did you get this error?**
This is your migration creating the `comments` table:

```rb
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :post, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note the `foreign_key: true` part! That's telling Rails to add a foreign key constraint between `comments` and `posts` on the foreign key.

This is the test that is failing:

```rb
  test "should destroy post" do
    assert_difference('Post.count', -1) do
      delete post_url(@post)
    end


    assert_redirected_to posts_url
  end
```

It's deleting a `Post` record, which tells us that there is a row in the `comments` table with a `post_id` column referencing the Post we're trying to remove in this test, hence the failure.

**What can I do to fix it?**
First, you probably want to add an inverse relationship to your `Post` model, like this:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
```

Then you'll want to tell Rails how to handle associated records when you're removing a Post. You can do that with the `dependent` option, which [takes a handful of options](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent). I'll use `:delete_all` here, which tells Rails to use a single SQL query to delete all “dependent” comments (that is, comments that reference this Post) without loading them first:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

With that change your test should succeed because it will have removed the comments as well as the post in the same transaction, preventing the foreign key constraint from failing.